# CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Category' because it is not a delegate type 33 Active

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

Trying to generate items for a database using Bogus using this code:

```
var products = new Faker<Product>()
            .StrictMode(true)
            .RuleFor(e => e.Id, f => 0)
            .RuleFor(e => e.Name, (f, u) => f.Commerce.Product())
            .RuleFor(e => e.Price, (f, u) => Convert.ToDecimal(f.Commerce.Price()))
            .RuleFor(e => e.EanCode, (f, u) => f.Commerce.Ean8())
            .RuleFor(e => e.Category, (f, u) => f.Commerce.Categories(5));
```

And the Categories needed a int parameter but when I add it I get the error Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Category' because it is not a delegate type.

Comment: What is `Faker` here? What is the definition of `Product` too?

Comment: Is `Product.Category` a string in this instance? It looks that way, and that you are trying to assign in array os strings to it.

Comment: Faker is from the nuget Bogus and Product is my own class with properties which i am trying to randomize in random items from the bogus nuget.

public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string EanCode { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }

    }

Answer (score 0):

With this line:

```
.RuleFor(e => e.Category, (f, u) => f.Commerce.Categories(5))
```

You are returning a `string[]` with 5 values, and trying to assign it to a `string` property. Instead, you could do something like this which gets a n array or length 1, and then selects the first value from it:

```
.RuleFor(e => e.Category, (f, u) => f.Commerce.Categories(1)[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try adding

```
using System.Linq;
```

from this system class.

Please also add:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2022 so those are active by defeault but tried to add them anyways and still same problem

Comment: Can u post the Commerce class code

Comment: The commerce class is coming from the nuget Bogus so i cant.